# How to incorporate a Tic Tac Toe Restart Button

Tags: javascript, function, reset, tic-tac-toe

Making an arcade game on JavaScript. Hoping to put it into my github as a project. I was able to get all of my winning conditions done for my game, save for the draw condition that I still need to get done. I'm having trouble, however, incorporating a reset button on my game. I believe that its supposed to be an onBoardClick(event) that once pressed will reset the game state, but I'm a little confused as to how to go about incorporating it. I also know that I'm supposed to set my reset function to my button in the html. Would love some help on this last part.

My app.js

```js
let state;

const gameState = {
  players: ['x', 'o'],
  board: [
    null, null, null,
    null, null, null,
    null, null, null
  ]
// one way I was that after every single instance of placing the X or O
// I should have my program check if it met the victory condition
//looking to get an array
}

    //needs to be in this order
    //event listener after function
const gameArea = document.getElementById('gameBoard');
    // ^ use this for cells

let playerXTurn = true;

function checkWin1(playerIcon) {
  let gameWon = true; //diagonal L to R
  for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
    if(gameState.board[i*4]!=playerIcon){
      gameWon = false;
      break;
    }
  } return gameWon
}

function checkWin2(playerIcon){
  gameWon = true; //diagonal R to L
  for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
    if(gameState.board[(i*2)+2]!=playerIcon){
      gameWon = false;
      break;
    }
  } return gameWon
}

function checkWin3(playerIcon){
  gameWon = true; //0 3 6 down
  for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
    if(gameState.board[(i*3)]!=playerIcon){
      gameWon = false;
      break;
    }
  } return gameWon
}

function checkWin4(playerIcon){
  gameWon = true; //0 1 2 across
    for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
      if(gameState.board[i]!=playerIcon){
        gameWon = false;
        break;
      }
    } return gameWon
}

function checkWin5(playerIcon){
  gameWon = true; //3 4 5 across
    for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
      if(gameState.board[(i+2)+1]!=playerIcon){
        gameWon = false;
        break;
      }
    } return gameWon
}

function checkWin6(playerIcon){
  gameWon = true; //6 7 8 across
    for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
      if(gameState.board[(i+5)+1]!=playerIcon){
        gameWon = false;
        break;
      }
    } return gameWon
}

function checkWin7(playerIcon){
  gameWon = true; //1 4 7 down
    for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
      if(gameState.board[(i*3)+1]!=playerIcon){
        gameWon = false;
        break;
      }
    } return gameWon
}

function checkWin8(playerIcon){
  gameWon = true; //2 5 8 down
    for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
      if(gameState.board[(i*2)+2+i]!=playerIcon){
        gameWon = false;
        break;
      }
    } return gameWon
}



    //onBoardClick is like actually writing with the pen
function onBoardClick(event){
const cellClass = event.target.classList;
  if(cellClass.contains('X_BoardPiece')||cellClass.contains('O_BoardPiece')){
    return;
  } 

  let cellId = event.target.id.substring(5);
  //will store the value in this variable
  // cellId is storing our number and we can plug them into the array (of course
  //we need to start at -1 for each number bc arrays begin at 0
  

  if (playerXTurn) {
    event.target.classList.add('X_BoardPiece')
    //^ we added the X as a class
    //'event''target''classList' all objects
    console.log(event.target.id.substring(5))
    //provides a way to check which cell is clicked
    //crops out the first 5 characters leaving only 1,2 etc
    gameState.board[cellId-1] = 'x'
    const isWinner = checkWin1('x') || checkWin2('x') || checkWin3('x') || checkWin4('x') || checkWin5('x') || checkWin6('x') || checkWin7('x') || checkWin8('x')
    if (isWinner) {
      alert ("player x is the winner")
    }
    //invokes gamestate
    //has two properties: player and board
    // use '.' to access which one specificially
  }
  else {
    event.target.classList.add('O_BoardPiece')
    console.log(event.target.id.substring(5))
    gameState.board[cellId-1] = 'o'
    const isWinner = checkWin1('o') || checkWin2('o') || checkWin3('o') || checkWin4('o') || checkWin5('o') || checkWin6('o') || checkWin7('o') || checkWin8('o')
    if (isWinner) {
      alert ("player o is the winner")
    }
  }

  console.log(gameState.board)
  playerXTurn = !playerXTurn
}

gameArea.addEventListener('click', onBoardClick);
```

My index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="./app.js" defer> </script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<h1 id="Title"> Tic Tac Toe </h1>

<p id="gameDescription"> 
    A simple game of Tic Tac Toe. 
    Player One starts with 'X' and Player Two follows with 'O'. 
    Goal is to see who will be the first to match 3 in a row 
</p>

<h2 id="playAgain"> Play Again? </h2>
<button id="resetButton"> Reset Game </button>

<body>
    <div class="gameBoard" id="gameBoard">
        <div class="ticTacToeCell" id="cell-1"></div>
        <div class="ticTacToeCell" id="cell-2"></div>
        <div class="ticTacToeCell" id="cell-3"></div>
        <div class="ticTacToeCell" id="cell-4"></div>
        <div class="ticTacToeCell" id="cell-5"></div>
        <div class="ticTacToeCell" id="cell-6"></div>
        <div class="ticTacToeCell" id="cell-7"></div>
        <div class="ticTacToeCell" id="cell-8"></div>
        <div class="ticTacToeCell" id="cell-9"></div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I tried to do a function onBoardClick(event) on the button but it didn't work. I think I may have targeted the object incorrectly.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the shortest code necessary to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Think of your data (or `gameState`) as what describes your UI (aka the UI is like a function of your state, updating whenever it receives a new state for consistency). That being said, it might help you to literally create a `render()` function that takes in the `gameState` and updates the UI accordingly.

If you implement `render()`, then a reset button's event handler should simply set your `gameState` to its initial, default value, and then call `render()` with the new state.

Moreover, within every call to `onBoardClick()`, update the state according to the user action, and then also call `render()` with the new state.

However, you must make sure that `gameState` is properly capturing all aspects of the game's state. For example, the current player's turn, which you track with `playerXTurn` is also a part of the game's state, so it makes sense to include it within `gameState` as well.

Here's a full implementation for reference:

```js
const gameBoard = document.getElementById("gameBoard");
const resetBtn = document.getElementById("resetButton");

let gameState = {
  currentTurn: "X",
  board: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
  isDone: false,
};

// The UI is a function of the game state
function render(state) {
  const newCells = []; // array of cells of the new UI.
  for (const cell of state.board) {

    // initialize new cell from state
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("ticTacToeCell");
    div.id = newCells.length;
    if (cell !== null) {
      div.textContent = cell;
    }

    // add to array of new cells
    newCells.push(div);
  }

  // replace the old UI with the new UI
  gameBoard.replaceChildren(...newCells);
}

function checkWin1(playerIcon) {
  let gameWon = true; //diagonal L to R
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (gameState.board[i * 4] != playerIcon) {
      gameWon = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return gameWon;
}

function checkWin2(playerIcon) {
  gameWon = true; //diagonal R to L
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (gameState.board[i * 2 + 2] != playerIcon) {
      gameWon = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return gameWon;
}

function checkWin3(playerIcon) {
  gameWon = true; //0 3 6 down
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (gameState.board[i * 3] != playerIcon) {
      gameWon = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return gameWon;
}

function checkWin4(playerIcon) {
  gameWon = true; //0 1 2 across
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (gameState.board[i] != playerIcon) {
      gameWon = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return gameWon;
}

function checkWin5(playerIcon) {
  gameWon = true; //3 4 5 across
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (gameState.board[i + 2 + 1] != playerIcon) {
      gameWon = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return gameWon;
}

function checkWin6(playerIcon) {
  gameWon = true; //6 7 8 across
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (gameState.board[i + 5 + 1] != playerIcon) {
      gameWon = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return gameWon;
}

function checkWin7(playerIcon) {
  gameWon = true; //1 4 7 down
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (gameState.board[i * 3 + 1] != playerIcon) {
      gameWon = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return gameWon;
}

function checkWin8(playerIcon) {
  gameWon = true; //2 5 8 down
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (gameState.board[i * 2 + 2 + i] != playerIcon) {
      gameWon = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return gameWon;
}

function checkForWin(player) {
  return (
    checkWin1(player) ||
    checkWin2(player) ||
    checkWin3(player) ||
    checkWin4(player) ||
    checkWin5(player) ||
    checkWin6(player) ||
    checkWin7(player) ||
    checkWin8(player)
  );
}

//onBoardClick is like actually writing with the pen
function onBoardClick(event) {
  const cellId = event.target.id;

  // check the move is valid
  if (gameState.board[cellId] !== null || gameState.isDone) {
    return;
  }

  // update the state
  gameState.board[cellId] = gameState.currentTurn;

  const isWinner = checkForWin(gameState.currentTurn);
  if (isWinner) {
    gameState.isDone = true;
    render(gameState); // update UI

    // prevents painting from getting blocked by main thread
    setTimeout(() => alert(`Player ${gameState.currentTurn} is the winner`));
  } else {
    gameState.currentTurn = gameState.currentTurn === "X" ? "O" : "X"; // update player turn
    render(gameState); // update UI
  }
}

function resetGame() {
  // reset to initial value
  gameState = {
    currentTurn: "X",
    board: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    isDone: false,
  };

  render(gameState); // update UI
}

gameBoard.addEventListener("click", onBoardClick);
resetBtn.addEventListener("click", resetGame);
```

```css
.gameBoard {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 50px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 50px);
}

.ticTacToeCell {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="Title">Tic Tac Toe</h1>
<p id="gameDescription">
  A simple game of Tic Tac Toe. Player One starts with 'X' and Player Two follows with 'O'. Goal
  is to see who will be the first to match 3 in a row
</p>

<button id="resetButton">Reset Game</button>

<div class="gameBoard" id="gameBoard">
  <div class="ticTacToeCell" id="0"></div>
  <div class="ticTacToeCell" id="1"></div>
  <div class="ticTacToeCell" id="2"></div>
  <div class="ticTacToeCell" id="3"></div>
  <div class="ticTacToeCell" id="4"></div>
  <div class="ticTacToeCell" id="5"></div>
  <div class="ticTacToeCell" id="6"></div>
  <div class="ticTacToeCell" id="7"></div>
  <div class="ticTacToeCell" id="8"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer, definite upvote.